# "...Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2 (...) does not exist" error when creating a new Sparksession, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

So I'm super new on everything Spark and I'm pulling my hair out trying to find out why I'm getting this error. This is what I've done so far:

- I installed the most recent Java
- Installed Python; I first installed 3.8 but when I went to the console and wrote "pip install jupyter lab" I got an error; so I had to downgrade to the most recent 3.7.x... no error then...
- Through the cmd console I wrote "pip install pyspark==2.3.2" (Note: I had already tried with the simpler "pip install pyspark" but got the same error below)
- I went to jupyter lab and wrote my first 3 lines:

> from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, count, sum, when
>
> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>
> from pyspark import SparkContext

no errors there

- But then I wrote:

> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("app1").getOrCreate()

and I got this gigantic error, I run out of ideas on why this is happening. And just to be clear; my first installation was with Anaconda Navigator and I got the same error! ... any help about this will be greatly appreciated:

````
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b5258aee5a77> in <module>
----> 1 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("app1").getOrCreate()

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    171                     for key, value in self._options.items():
    172                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
--> 173                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    174                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
    175                     for key, value in self._options.items():

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    349         with SparkContext._lock:
    350             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 351                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    352             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    353 

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 118                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    119         except:
    120             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    187         self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server(auth_token)
    188         (host, port) = self._accumulatorServer.server_address
--> 189         self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port, auth_token)
    190         self._jsc.sc().register(self._javaAccumulator)
    191 

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1523         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1524         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1525             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1526 
   1527         for temp_arg in temp_args:

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    330                 raise Py4JError(
    331                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
--> 332                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    333         else:
    334             raise Py4JError(

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.String]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````